# I have a large file want to process using panda in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large file text file separated by tab that is of 6.9 GB. I want to read it by using pandas. I have tried many code but not succeeded. Following is the code I'm using:

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv('path/Table_CpG__Avg_methylation_data.txt', sep = '\t', iterator=True,):

    chunk.dtypes
    g = pd.DataFrame(data = chunk)
    g.dtypes
    g['v3']=g[['v1']]+1

    dff_meth= g[['v2','v1','v3','Avg_of_Methy']]
    dff_meth.to_csv("path/Table_All_CpG_methylation_data.bed", sep='\t',index=False,index_label=None)
```

But this code is not working. If any one could be of some help

Comment: Please be more specific. In what way is your code not working? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want something like this:

```
chunksize = 10**6    
for chunk in pd.read_csv('input_file', sep = '\t', chunksize = chunksize):
    # Your code goes here... for example:
    chunk.iloc[:,3]=chunk.iloc[:,1]+1     
    dff_meth = chunk.iloc[:,[1,3]]
    # chunk is already a data frame, so no need to use pd.DataFrame(data = chunk)
    # If you want to print dtypes:
    print(chunk.dtypes)

    #finally we write to an output file, appending:
    dff_meth.to_csv('output_file', sep='\t', index=False, index_label=None, header = None , mode = 'a')
```

Try with some smaller file and a small chunksize to see if it does what you want.

Comment: I actually want to read multiple files line by line and found the code frm net which after reading lines dont show whats in rows variable:

Comment: import sys
import glob
import errno
path = '/home/filesnamet'   
filenames = glob.glob(path)  
files = [open(i, "r") for i in filenames]     rows = izip(*files).idontr know how to parse "rows" and error is <itertools.izip object at 0x7fb6efb65f80>

Comment: @Ahsan I'm not sure what you want to do. Do you want to 1) read one file after another? or 2) read all files simultaneously and combine their corresponding lines? Your code with `izip` should do 2) (when correctly written). And `rows` is an iterator, so you need for example `for i in rows: do something with i`. Maybe you should ask another question because it's a bit different thing. 
But if you want 1) then you only need to add another loop`for file in filenames: for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=...,...):` Or if files are rather small you may skip `chunksize`.

Comment: hi, i have shifted to python to read multiple files simultaneously line by line. I dont know how to loop over some task until all files reached to EOF.I have a large code for that I dont know how to share that.Please help me in this case coz i m totally struck and also new to python.My aim is to merge multiple files  (already sorted) by matching column no.2.I dont know how to explain further

Comment: @Ahsan If I understand correctly, you want to take column 2 from each file and combine these columns, side by side, into one array (i.e. a data frame or a csv file), right? I suppose files are large (several GB). Do all files have the same number of rows? And how many files are there?

Comment: I'll try to help. But if you think this problem is only loosely related to your original question, then you may consider writing a new question. That way more people would have the chance to see it.

Comment: i have written a new q. and i am appylying condition that if column 2 value is same in whatever the files paste their 3rd column in a row.and then search that which file has the smallest value of 2nd column.then do the same job with that records until all files ar read.yes each file is around 3GB and i have 62 files to merge

Comment: this chunk code is nt working :ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 116, in __setitem__

Comment: I'm not sure what happens. You could try commenting out some lines inside `for` loop (or all). Maybe indexing is wrong somewhere, or maybe the separator should be set to `sep = '\s+'`...

Comment: iter_csv = pd.read_csv('SRR2876086Sorted_Coverage.txt', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
i am using this code to read a file by chunk and want to convert it to np.array so that i may merge the read files chunk by chunk.

Comment: I think you don't need both `iterator` and `chunksize` at the same time. Please, take a look it [these examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) from pandas docs.

Comment: @Ahsan do not edit an answer to your question elaborating on your question - you can edit your own question if you need to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You are missing chunksize parameter.

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv('your_file.txt', sep ='\t', chunksize = chunksize):
    #your code
```

Complete documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @Ahsan Also, note that you need an append mode in `to_csv` (see my answer). Otherwise you'll get only the last chunk of data in the output.